# Difference between Meteor.Publish/Subscribe & Amplify.Publish/Subscribe?

Tags: meteor

What is the difference between `Meteor.Publish`/`Meteor.Subscribe` & `Amplify.Publish`/`Amplify.Subscribe` in MeteorJS?

Answer (score 1):

Meteor's publish and subscribe have a lot more going on as subscribe runs on the client and publish on the server. Data is transferred over the wire by means of DDP.

Amplify's version is much simpler in that it only facilitates message passing on the client OR the server.